# twp C++ questions, 1. C2228 left of.. must have class 2.change type of return from function

Tags: c++, class

I need some help with my homework. I have this code on "rational.cpp":

```
bool Rational::operator!=(const Rational num)
{
if ((getMone() == num.getMone()) && (getMechane() == num.getMechane()))
    return false;
return true;
}
//and this is work well... really returns true or false

string Rational::printTF(bool A)
{
if (A)
    return "true";
    return "false";
}
```

and in my main.cpp:

```
<code><pre>cout << (a != b).printTF();</pre></code>
```

and I get this error:

Error   C2228   left of '.printTF' must have class/struct/union Rational    main.cpp    40 (that the 'cout' code..)

What's wrong here?

Is there any way, to send for example, to a boolean function, and return string?

Or in my code, to send to a Rational (number - 1/1) class (which should return fraction) and if it have value of "0" for example just return "0" without /..

I tried to return NULL, or to send to a bool or int function and then return.. and always return fruction..

**Marinos**, the penny drops.. understand my mistake... It makes me wonder again what exacly they want from us...

Regarding to the second question, in my question I need to do it for an operator... 
Like that:

```
Rational Rational::operator-(Rational num)
{
    Rational tmp[3];
    tmp[0] = multFraction(num);
    tmp[1] = num.multFraction(*this);
    tmp[2].mone = tmp[0].mone - tmp[1].mone;
    tmp[2].mechane = tmp[0].mechane;

    if (checNumber(tmp[2]))
    {
        string printOne = tmp[2].mone;
        return printOne;
    }
    return reducingNumber(tmp[2]);
}
```

(I know that the return doesn't work.. just wonder how can I do something like that..)

**Serge**, I tried your seggest, and it works... but.... They asked us specific to do it in that way: (a!=b).print();
so I need to figure out what they meant. But its good to know!!

Comment: One question per question please. See: [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the error is obviously here

```
(a != b).printTF();
```

what do you expect this to do? you're calling the member function `printTF` of a non-class built-in `bool` temporary object.. `(a!=b)` will result in either `true` or `false`; in both cases it's non-sensical to ask for e.g. `false.printTF();`... Can't offer you a solution 'cause I don't really know what you'd expect this to do.

Regarding your other question, sure you can, e.g.:

```
std::string aFunction(bool b) {
  // do something with b
  std::string result = "something";
  return result;
}
```

or with your class

```
std::string aFunction(Rational r) {
  // do something with r
  std::string result = "0";
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare the method `printTF` to operate on a `Rational` object taking a bool parameter, but you use it directly on a bool, so the error: the expression `(a != b)` is a `bool` not a `Rational`.

You should declare the method `printTF` as `static` since it does not use any object:

```
static std::string Rational::printTF(bool A)
{
if (A)
    return "true";
    return "false";
}
```

and use it that way:

```
cout << Rational::printTF(a != b);
```